# A way to get the number of footnotes on current page?

Tags: footnotes, indexing

Is there one? (I want this because I want to make the index format `7 n.\,1` if there is more than one note on the page and `7\,n`.

PS. More clearly stated, as requested: could one define a macro `\fnnonthispage` that returned the number of footnotes on the current page? I don't know how to say it more clearly.

PS II. Here is how the macro might be used.  On the first page, there are two notes, so the entry should specify the number; but of p. 2, there is only one, and so there the number should not be specified.  If a page contains a partial footnote, that should also count as one.

```
%compile with: pdflatex file; makeindex file; pdflatex file
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeindex

% \see{} inserts a see in the next entry, after the pp. 
\def\seeentry{}
% must be global to work within footnote
\def\see#1{\gdef\seeentry{#1}} 
\def\seesep{;\space}
\def\seetext{see\space}

% \index{<entry>|fn} marks the ref. as to a note
\def\fn#1#2{% insert see if \seeentry is not empty
\hyperpage{#2} n.\,#1\ifx\seeentry\empty\else\seesep\seetext\seeentry\def\seeentry{}\fi%
% ----- here is how the desired macro could be used:
%\hyperpage{#2}%
%\ifnum\fnnonthispage>1
%\space n.\,#1\ifx\seeentry\empty\else\seesep\seetext\seeentry\def\seeentry{}\fi%
%\else
%\,n.\ifx\seeentry\empty\else\seesep\seetext\seeentry\def\seeentry{}\fi%
%\fi
}%

% Redefining \index to mark reff. to notes as such.
\LetLtxMacro{\oldindex}{\index}
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{%
\if@noftnote%
\oldindex{#1}%
\else%
\oldindex{#1|fn{\number\value{footnote}}}
\fi%
}

\begin{document}
Cheese.\footnote{\index{cake}cake.}
Whether it be cheese or not.\footnote{What?}
\newpage
Oranges are called Chinese apples in German.\footnote{And in
Danish, of course.\index{Danish}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just use `\thefootnote`?

Comment: @Andrew, but that won't tell me whether there will be more footnotes before the end of the page. I mean the number of footnotes, not the number of the footnote.

Comment: you can write to external file `.aux` for example.

Comment: @touhami, sounds good, please elaborate.

Comment: I will try. Note that it's not clear for me how do you plan to use it.

Comment: @touhami, thanks. If you prefer it, I can give a minimal example first. But you'd have to give me some time.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you want? It is very unclear from what you have written. It would help f you gave more details and an example. If possible include a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that at least show what you have tried.

Comment: @Andrew, yes, as I said in the comment above yours, I will provide an example.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55460/8528) help? I could revise it if you clarify your question with some actual (minimal! -- see Andrew's comment) code.

Comment: The key problem is what happens if a footnote occurs in a paragraph which gets split at the end of a page.  The footnote counter should get incremented before the everypage hook.  To get a reliable number you would have to use \protected@write{auxout} to record ever footnote and what page it occurred on, then count them up the next \begin{document}.  (Doesn't cleverref already do something iike that?)

Comment: @touhami, I've added an example and a way to use the macro I'm asking for.

Comment: Off-topic: Why did you delete the query, [Junicode with discretionary ligatures seems to interpret ix in fix as Roman numeral](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296458/5001)? I'd be happy to share a very simple solution that involves the `selnolig` package. :-)

Comment: @mico, thanks, I deleted it because I thought of that myself.

Comment: That's OK. I've decided to post a query on my own on this topic -- see [How to keep a “rare” ligature from interfering with a “common” ligature?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296512/5001) Feel free to submit a `selnolig`-based solution. :-)

Comment: @mico, I just disabled ix and iv (they didn't look like ligatures anyway). I don't know how to do it conditionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. We check if there is more than one footnote at every output page, if no  a macro `\mtfnexiste<pagenumber>` is defined.

**Note** John Kormylo's comment above is important but I did not take care of the point here. Let me know.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeindex

% \see{} inserts a see in the next entry, after the pp. 
\def\seeentry{}
% must be global to work within footnote
\def\see#1{\gdef\seeentry{#1}} 
\def\seesep{;\space}
\def\seetext{see\space}

% \index{<entry>|fn} marks the ref. as to a note

\newcounter{mtfn}
\setcounter{mtfn}{1}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@outputpage{\stepcounter{page}}{%
\ifnum\value{mtfn}<\value{footnote}
\expandafter\gdef\csname mtfnexiste\thepage\endcsname{x}\fi
\setcounter{mtfn}{\value{footnote}}\stepcounter{mtfn}%
\stepcounter{page}}{}{\errmessage{no}}


\def\fn#1#2{% insert see if \seeentry is not empty
\hyperpage{#2}%
\expandafter\ifx\csname mtfnexiste\@secondoftwo#2\endcsname\relax
\,n.\ifx\seeentry\empty\else\seesep\seetext\seeentry\def\seeentry{}\fi%
\else
\space n.\,#1\ifx\seeentry\empty\else\seesep\seetext\seeentry\def\seeentry{}\fi%
\fi
}%
\makeatother

% Redefining \index to mark reff. to notes as such.
\LetLtxMacro{\oldindex}{\index}
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{%
\if@noftnote%
\oldindex{#1}%
\else%
\oldindex{#1|fn{\number\value{footnote}}}
\fi%
}

\begin{document}
Cheese.\footnote{\index{cake}cake.}
Whether it be cheese or not.\footnote{What?}
\newpage
Oranges are called Chinese apples in German.\footnote{And in
Danish, of course.\index{Danish}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

**Update** exemple of long footnote it is the 2 nd footnote in first page but the indexed word is in second page with only one footnote in it so the problem!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeindex

% \see{} inserts a see in the next entry, after the pp. 
\def\seeentry{}
% must be global to work within footnote
\def\see#1{\gdef\seeentry{#1}} 
\def\seesep{;\space}
\def\seetext{see\space}

% \index{<entry>|fn} marks the ref. as to a note

\newcounter{mtfn}
\setcounter{mtfn}{1}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@outputpage{\stepcounter{page}}{%
\ifnum\value{mtfn}<\value{footnote}
\expandafter\gdef\csname mtfnexiste\thepage\endcsname{x}\fi
\setcounter{mtfn}{\value{footnote}}\stepcounter{mtfn}%
\stepcounter{page}}{}{\errmessage{no}}


\def\fn#1#2{% insert see if \seeentry is not empty
\hyperpage{#2}%
\expandafter\ifx\csname mtfnexiste\@secondoftwo#2\endcsname\relax
\,n.\ifx\seeentry\empty\else\seesep\seetext\seeentry\def\seeentry{}\fi%
\else
\space n.\,#1\ifx\seeentry\empty\else\seesep\seetext\seeentry\def\seeentry{}\fi%
\fi
}%
\makeatother

% Redefining \index to mark reff. to notes as such.
\LetLtxMacro{\oldindex}{\index}
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{%
\if@noftnote%
\oldindex{#1}%
\else%
\oldindex{#1|fn{\number\value{footnote}}}
\fi%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\footnote{bla bla}
\lipsum[1-2]
\footnote{very very long long footnote
very very long long footnote very very long long footnote
very very long long footnote very very long long footnote
very very long long footnote very very long long footnote
very very long long footnote very very long long footnote
very very long long footnote very very long long footnote
very very long long footnote very very long long footnote
very very long long footnote very very long long footnote
very very long long footnote very very long long footnote
very very long long footnote very very long long footnote
very very long long footnote very very long long footnote
cake\index{cake}}
\lipsum[1-2]
\footnote{last bla bla}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How does this (not) handle partial notes?

Comment: please see update.

Comment: aha, so the part that carries over from p.1 doesn't count as a footnote on p. 2, I see.

Comment: one can work around, if you want I can see this later.