# How to Add an Italicized `n' After the Page Number in Certain Index Entries

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex

I am in the process of typesetting a book that was published in 1877; and which has some unusual index entries; more specifically, an *n* appears after the listed page number:

[image]

For example, notice ``Abbots'' where after the page number 257, is added an $n$.

This, in fact, seems to occur frequently, although I don't know what the $n$ signifies.

QUESTION:
I would like to know if it is possible, using Latex, to insert this $n$ after the page number for each index entry where it occurs?

I am using a rather basic approach to generating the index:

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
```

Where, for instance, the code

```
\index{Alcock, John@{Alcock, John, bishop of Ely}}
```

produces the output

[image]

Incidentally, does anyone know what this $n$ signifies?

Comment: Do you have the whole book? Can't you check, if the index marked by _n_ is pointing to a footnote?

Comment: I would have thought the n denotes a note (either footnote or endnote). If that is indeed the case, you want to see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55431/footnote-numbers-in-index-e-g-23n3

Comment: In fact, your book is "Rise and Growth of the Anglican Schism" by Nicholas Sander. If you go onto page 11, you will find no mention of Alcock, bishop of Ely in the main text. However, if you look at Footnote 1, you will see said name mentioned. @DG' s interpretation is surely correct.

Comment: @Willie Wong Thank you for pointing this out. I misinterpreted DG'S comment; yes, the reference to Alcock is contained in a footnote. There are many, many lengthy footnotes in this book. That would explain why there are so many n's in the Index. I can now easliy check that. Thanks again.